# how to get push data outside of map method

Tags: javascript, console, push, array.prototype.map

In below i have share my codes where i can't able to get push data when i call arr in outside.

I,m tring to get push data in outside of .map() method where i only get empty array by console.log(arr).

inside the method i've using one more console which is given push data but outside of methods console is given an empty array. how to get push data for outside of method in here?

Anyone can help me to get push data using this codes,
Thanks for your tring!

```
    let arr = []


   useEffect(() => {
       x?.map(async (id) => {
         
            await fetch(`https://www.roads.com/roads/api/web/bk/${id}`)
                
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((data) => {

                    arr.push((data?.data?.latitude), (data?.data?.longitude));
                    console.log(arr);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });

        })
       
    }, [])
    

    console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score -1):

Map will not work with await, so please use for loop instead of map function, or use this method.

await Promise.all(array.map(async (item) => {  } ) );

Comment: i have tried for loop which is not working for me.

Comment: besides, await Promise.all(array.map(async (item) => { } ) ); this should be used in  instead of x?.map(async (id) => {} this or if you help me to clear one more ?